# Document Security in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server

How I add column level security to a document in a SharePoint 2013 document library? And then how can I audit it reasonably?

Comment: What do you mean column level security? Do you mean security over the metadata, or security within the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of column-level security: (1) Data in certain columns on items/documents are visible/not visible to certain users. (2) The whole item is visible/not visible to users based on a value in a certain column. Not sure which one you are going for, but if option 1, you will have to implement custom code or get a third party solution. Bamboo solutions has a [good option](http://store.bamboosolutions.com/sharepoint-column-level-security.aspx).  Beware with column level security that you will run into performance issues if you are trying to apply the security to large lists.  For Option 2, I would use workflow to set permissions on the item based on the metadata of the item/document. [This](http://spcycle.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-create-workflow-to-change-item.html) is a good example of this

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint does not natively support column level security. If you have some kind of workflow where you want different users to see different columns you can do this with creative view building. But if some field, like a SSN number, cannot be visible to other users then you might need a third party product. [EasyBox](http://easydynamics.com/products/#go_easybox) would let you keep data about objects tied to but permission isolated from your objects.